# Control-M GPG: mdc_packet with invalid encoding, decryption failed

Tags: encryption, gnupg, mainframe, control-m

I am using Control-M AFT for decryption. The encrypted source file is pulled from Mainframe and while decrypting the file using GnuPG, it fails with below error

gpg: mdc_packet with invalid encoding
gpg: decryption failed: Invalid packet

When trying to decrypt manually, it gives the same error message but the file is decrypted. But from control-m, file is not decrypted and the job fails

Comment: How are you transferring the file from the mainframe.  Control-M for AFT is BMC's product?  the most likely issue is the transfer is failing or you are not getting the complete message.  I'd do an SHA512 has on the file on the mainframe and compare that to the file transferred to the local system and ensure the file is correct before investigating the error message from gpg.